# Lenovo 110s netbook keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, live-usb

I have a netbook, a Lenovo 110s-11IBR netbook. The built in keyboard isn't working at all with my Ubuntu Live USB. The OS works fine with the WiFi, at least to the point that I see the network, but I'm unable to type the password to connect. My USB mouse also works fine. I'm hesitant to actually replace my Windows with Ubuntu (not enough storage for both) untill I know my netbook will retain full functionality. How do I get my keyboard working?

Comment: What sort of keyboard settings did you choose when starting the live session?

Comment: I've not set any keyboard settings, I'm a noob at this.

Comment: Ok, using defaults then. This is an odd problem, I have an older version of that netbook.

Comment: Oddly enough, I just rebooted and it's working now. Any idea why it happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Some other users with similar Lenovo. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350394 Many UEFI/BIOS settings important.